# How to stop the x-axis labels from getting cut off from the bottom of the bar graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here's my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.bar(x_labels, y_labels, width=0.9)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

This yields this graph: [image: matplotlib sucks]

As you can see, the bottoms of the labels keep getting cut off. I know one solution is to use `plt.savefig('rest.png', bbox_inches='tight')` but how do I fit it all without using that argument in `savefig()`? How can I achieve that effect of `bbox_inches='tight'` without using `plt.savefig()`? What else can be done to fit it all?

Comment: You can try ```plt.tight_layout()```. If that still doesn't give the desired results you can use ```plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)``` (adjusting ```bottom``` as necessary).

Comment: Neither of them have any effect on the final graph.

Comment: When you say there is no effect are you still saving the plot with ```bbox_inches='tight'```?

Comment: No. If I save it with like that, I don't have to use those methods (neither `tight_layout()` nor `subplots_adjust()`). I am saving the image, however.

Comment: I think you might have to share more of your code. It sounds like something else is going wrong.

Comment: I isolated the relevant portions of my code to a new file and `plt.tight_layout()` works in the new file so you were right in that something else was interfering.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you're sorted!

Answer (score 0):

try giving the x-axis a little bit of a buffer

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.6)
```

Comment: I've tried this but it seems to have absolutely no effect. I've added lots of lines of code that end up resulting in no change to the final graph.

Answer (score 0):

The line that worked for me while I was working on long tick marks was:

```py
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).